# WinSCP Session.ExecuteCommand does not wait for tomcat5_3 stop/start to finish

Tags: tomcat, winscp, winscp-net

I want to control status of my Tomcat server from ASP.NET. So basically I  execute the following commands:

```
sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat5_3 status
sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat5_3 stop
sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat5_3 start
```

I use a simple call of method `Session.ExecuteCommand` from WinSCP .NET assembly like below:

```csharp
public string ExecScript(string cmd)
{
    try
    {
        CommandExecutionResult result = sessDB.ExecuteCommand(cmd);
        result.Check();
        return result.Output;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
    }
    return "";
}
```

I call `ExecScript` with one of these three commands:

```csharp
string result = ExecScript("sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat5_3 status");
```

The status command works fine. Always return a string so I am able to parse it and get a correct status of Tomcat.

But when I try to stop/start result should be something like below:

1st message

```
Stopping tomcat:
```

2nd part of message after a few seconds

```
Stopping tomcat:            [OK]
```

and then problem appears. Program of course does not show these messages, it just hangs, output window returns code 259 which as I know means "command still in progress".

In fact stop/start operation finishes with success. But my app does not inform me about it. No error, no exception, hung ...

Any hints, advices?

Comment: So does the `Session.ExecuteCommand` hang or return 259? It cannot do both.

Comment: code 259 appears in output window of VS. I guess it can come from IISExpress. Execute command hangs.  Your suggestion about background/foreground seems to be a good direction. :)